# Double candies during Helloween event 2017

Tags: pokemon-go

During this event when I transfer Pokémon or evolve it I will get double candies, but is this true for all situations when I can get candies? For example, does it work when I hatch an egg? Will I receive double number of candies for it? Or when I feed Pokémon in a gym, will I get 2 candies sometimes? Or is some another bonus which I did not notice yet? Now I know only when I use Nanab berry I will get a quadruple candies.

Comment: I've been wondering about the gym feeding candy. Haven't gotten any since the event started to confirm/deny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Niantic's own [update](https://pokemongolive.com/en/post/halloween2017):

> You’ll also earn extra Candy while you’re out trick-or-treating with your Buddy Pokémon: Candy rewards from **catching, hatching, and transferring Pokémon** will be doubled, and your buddy will find Candy twice as fast during the Halloween celebration!

(emphasis mine). So probably you will not get double candy for giving a berry at a gym, but the other you will get double candies for.

Comment: Are you sure about hatching? Yesterday I get +19 candies after hatch,

Comment: These are the official updates, so I have no reason to doubt this. What kind of egg (2km, 5km, 10km) did you hatch? 19 is reasonable for the lower ones

Comment: 2km but 19 can not be split 2. So that is reason why I doubt about it.

Comment: Ah, fair point. I don't know how 'double' is determined. If they take a random value between two values, and double those limits, or do a rounding of a random value, it will explain why you get an odd number of candies

Comment: Based on double Candy events in the past, they double the limits and still pick at random (or double the random value and round, which is technically the same). 19 is much more than you can usually get for a 2km egg.

Comment: its way higher than normal during these events.